# Selected record not displaying correctly in primefaces dataTable liveScroll

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm using primefaces 5.2 and jsf, in one of my page have datatable with live scroll. Once the page is loaded I'm displaying 5 records out of 23. Initially before scroll down if I'm selecting 1st record OR upto 5th record its displaying corresponding selected record correctly. but after using liveScroll to comes 23rd record, if i select any of the record not working.(first 5 working)
Again I'm selecting first 5 records one by one of dataTable its showing 15th,16th upto 20th record.

XHTMl:

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="DTAlterColor blueborder mytable" var="data"
    rowkey="#{data.planName}" style="margin-top:60px"
    value="#{draftplanbean.lazyPlanList}" scrollRows="5" lazy="true"
    scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="150"
    id="reqListdtdrft" widgetVar="viewdt0" sortOrder="descending">


    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>

            <p:column headerText="Plan Name" rowspan="2"
                style="width:100px;height:25px" styleClass="mainheadertxt">
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="Version" rowspan="2"
                style="width:40px;height:25px" styleClass="mainheadertxt">
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Created By" rowspan="2"
                style="width:100px;height:25px" styleClass="mainheadertxt">

            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Created On" rowspan="2"
                style="width:180px;height:25px" styleClass="mainheadertxt">
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Last Updated By"
                style="width:100px;height:25px" styleClass="mainheadertxt"
                rowspan="2">
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Last Updated On"
                style="width:180px;height:25px" styleClass="mainheadertxt"
                rowspan="2">
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Plan Status" style="width:100px;height:25px"
                styleClass="mainheadertxt" rowspan="2">

            </p:column>

        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column style="height:25px">
        <p:commandLink
            actionListener="#{draftplanbean.savePlanId(data.planId,data.version)}"
            update="firstform:lefttabview:diagramfrm,firstform:lefttabview:headingdrafts, firstform:lefttabview:draftlink"
            style="text-decoration: none;outline:0">
            <f:actionListener
                binding="#{draftplanbean.saveFlag(data.approvedFlag)}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{data.planName}" styleClass="lighttxt" />
        </p:commandLink>

    </p:column>

    <p:column style="height:25px">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.version}" styleClass="lighttxt" />
    </p:column>


    <p:column style="height:25px">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.plan_createdby}" styleClass="lighttxt" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="height:25px">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.plan_createdon}" styleClass="lighttxt" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="height:25px">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.plan_updatedby}" styleClass="lighttxt" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="height:25px">
        <h:outputText value="#{data.plan_updatedon}" styleClass="lighttxt" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="height:25px">

        <h:outputText rendered="#{data.approvedFlag==0}" value="Draft"
            styleClass="lighttxt" />
        <h:outputText rendered="#{data.approvedFlag==3}"
            value="Pending For Approval" styleClass="lighttxt" />
        <h:outputText id="reworktxt" rendered="#{data.approvedFlag==4}"
            value="Rework" styleClass="lighttxt" />
        <p:tooltip id="toltip1" for="reworktxt" value="#{data.reworkcomment}"
            trackMouse="true" rendered="#{data.approvedFlag==4}" />

    </p:column>



</p:dataTable>




<div style="margin-top: 5px">

    <h:outputText id="headingdrafts" value="Plan: #{fcbean.pname}"
        styleClass="subtxt" />
```

Managed Bean:

public DraftPlanBean() {

```
    lazyPlanList = new DraftPlanView(getPlans(), draft);

}
```

Modal:

```
protected int statusflag;

public DraftPlanView(List<PlanVO> datasource, int statusflag) {
    this.datasource = datasource;
    this.statusflag = statusflag;
}


public List<PlanVO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

    Map<String, String> filtersnew = ConUtil.convertFilters(filters);

    setFilterGlobal(filtersnew);

    String globalSortField = (String) SessionMgr.getSessionData("globalsortkey");

    return load1(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filtersnew,  globalSortField);
}

public void setFilterGlobal(Map<String, String> filters) {

    if (SessionMgr.getSessionData("globalfilterkey") != null) {

        if (!SessionMgr.getSessionData("globalfilterkey").equals("")) {

            String filterKey = (String) SessionMgr.getSessionData("globalfilterkey");

            String filterVal = (String) SessionMgr.getSessionData("globalfiltervalue");

            filters.put(filterKey, filterVal);
        }
        if (SessionMgr.getSessionData("globalfilterkey").equals("clearfilter")) {

            filters.clear();

        }

    }

}

public List<PlanVO> load1(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, String> filters, String globalSortField) {

    PlanProcess pprocess = PlanProcess.getPlanProcess();

    List<PlanVO> lst = null;

    try {

        lst = pprocess.getDraftedPlansList(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters, SessionMgr.getProject(),
                statusflag, globalSortField);
        System.out.println("The list size is"+ lst.size());
        datasource.addAll(lst);
        if(lst.size()>0){
        this.setRowCount(pprocess.getPlansCount(filters, SessionMgr.getProject(), false, statusflag));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // temporary fix for exception handling
    }

    return lst;

}
```

}

I want to display selected record from dataTable,How can i do this?